# what is the specific usecase for !! in C++

Tags: c++, c

Came across using `!!` in C++ during condition check

```
if ( !! (flag != 0 )){..
}
```

This could be directly used like

```
if( flag != 0 ){..
}
```

Is there any specific corner use case in C/C++ or is it just a form of coding style ?

Comment: c and c++ are 2 very different languages, and often have very different answers. Please tag only one language.

Comment: It's a dumber way of writing `(bool)flag` - which is also compatible code between C and C++, unlike `!!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it's superfluous, but in general this style is used to convert the actual expression value to

- an integer type in `C`.
- a boolean type in `C++`.

Comment: Didn't you mean "to bool"?

Comment: @r3musn0x It's `int` in C.

Comment: ...unless it is C++ and operator `!` is overloaded...

Comment: More specifically, in C be it'd be used to convert a value to either 0 or 1. But regardless, in this case it's pointless since `!=` already guarantees to evaluate to either 0 or 1.  However, some people do it anyway because there's a common misconception that just because any non-zero value is truthy that boolean operators are allowed to produce any non-zero value as well.